# Dynamically switch parser while parsing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm parsing [spice netlists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPICE), for which I already have a parser. Since I actually use spectre (cadence, integrated electronics), I want to support both simulator languages (they differ, unfortunately). I could use a switch (e.g. commandline) and use the correct parser from start. However, spectre allows `simulator lang=spectre` statements, which I would also want to support (and vice versa, of course). How can this be done with boost::spirit?

My grammar looks roughly like this:

```
line = component_parser             | 
       command_parser               |  
       comment_parser               | 
       subcircuit_parser            | 
       subcircuit_instance_parser;

main = -line % qi::eol >> qi::eoi;
```

This toplevel structure is fine for both languages, so i need to change the subparsers. A first idea for me would be to have the toplevel parser hold instances (or objects) to the respective parser and to switch on finding the `simulator lang` statement (with a semantic action). Is this a good approach? If not, how else would one do this?

Comment: Have you tried just reassigning to `line` (or `main` or other suitable rule)?

Comment: I haven't tried anything up to now, but that's similar to what I thought about with different instances for the individual parsers. However, it's never easy with boost spirit, so I'm not sure if it's ok to switch parsers while actually using the parser to consume input. Also, perhaps there is a nice, spiritish way of doing things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`qi::lazy`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/lazy.html) (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/auxiliary/lazy.html).

There's an idiomatic pattern related to that, known as [The Nabialek Trick](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/nabialek-trick/).

I have several answers up on this site that show these various techniques.

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A85371+qi%3A%3Alazy